# Accelerometer outputs "WinRT transform error" when attempting to use it

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

In my WinRT application running on an ARM tablet (ie Surface), I'm trying to get events from the accelerometer sensor but it's not working. I attach to it this way, basically from Microsoft's example:

```
mAccelerometer = Accelerometer::GetDefault();
mListenerToken = mAccelerometer->ReadingChanged::add(ref new TypedEventHandler<Accelerometer^, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs^>(this, &AccelerometerWin8Delegate::ReadingChanged));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When an accelerometer event occurs, instead of getting my handler called, I get an error message in the output.

```
First-chance exception at 0x7539396B (KernelBase.dll) in EAMTestApp.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x80004002, 0x00000000, 0x00000027, 0x04B1F280).
```

The exception is thrown in KernelBase.dll!7539396a()

Any idea what could be causing this? The error message is very cryptic.

I've run the Microsoft example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Accelerometer-Sensor-Sample-22982671) with no problems on the Surface.

Comment: Have you enabled the capability for the accelerator?

Comment: From what I've seen, there's no explicit setting to enable capability for the accelerator. If it's unavailable, GetDefault() just returns nullptr. In my case there is an accelerator and I can attach an event handler, but when it tries to get fired I get the abovementioned exception instead.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, there doesn't seem to be a capability required. Try breaking on the exception itself. To do this, in Visual Studio, go to `Debug...Exceptions` then enable the exception. In this case, I think you can start off by just enabling the `WinRT Transform Error` exception which is under the `Win32 Exceptions` node. Hopefully this might narrow down the cause.